# Login sessions data and can we delete session from db in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I made login app using codeigniter 3.0.1, i'm facing couple of problems. First is things are not working when i don't check the 'remember me' check box and it still logs the user in when i close the browser and open it again with direct link "localhost/ci_login_app/index.php/account" seems like

> $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;

have no effect on it :/

i have configured config.php like this

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
#$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 60*60*24*7;

$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;

$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;

$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;

$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';

#$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;

$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

This is my authentication file uesr_authentication.php

```
<?php

Class User_Authentication extends CI_Controller 
{

public function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
}

// Show login page
public function index() 
{
    $this->load->view('layouts/header');
    $this->load->view('login_form');
    $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
}

public function user_login_process() 
{   

    $session_set_value = $this->session->all_userdata();

    // Check for remember_me data in retrieved session data
    if (isset($session_set_value['remember_me']) && $session_set_value['remember_me'] == "1") 
    {
        redirect('account');
    }       // Check for validation

    else{

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
        {
            $this->load->view('layouts/header');
            $this->load->view('login_form');
            $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
        } 

        else 
        {
                $result = $this->model_login->login_user();

                switch ($result) 
                {
                    case 'authenticated':
                    redirect('account');

                        break;
                    case 'incorrect_password':
                        echo "Error loging in, password not correct...!";
                        $this->load->view('layouts/header');
                        $this->load->view('login_form');
                        $this->load->view('layouts/footer'); 

                        break;

                    case 'not_activated':
                        echo "Please activate your account before logging in...!";
                        $this->load->view('layouts/header');
                        $this->load->view('login_form');
                        $this->load->view('layouts/footer'); 

                        break;

                    case 'incorrect_username':
                        echo "Error loging in, password/username not correct...!";
                        $this->load->view('layouts/header');
                        $this->load->view('login_form');
                        $this->load->view('layouts/footer'); 

                        break;

                    default:
                        echo "Enter correct value, press backspace";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

}

// Logout from admin page
public function logout() 
{

// Destroy session data
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $data['message_display'] = 'Successfully Logout';
    redirect('account');        
}
}
?>
```

This is my login.php controller

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('layouts/header');
    $this->load->view('login_form');        
    $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
}

public function login_user()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'User Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password ','trim|required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        echo "Validations doesn't run correctly!<br>";
        $this->load->view('layouts/header');
        $this->load->view('login_form');
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer');       
    }
    else
    {
        $result = $this->model_login->login_user();

        switch ($result) {
            case 'logged_in':
                redirect('home');
                // $this->load->view('admin_page');


                break;
            case 'incorrect_password':
                echo "Error loging in, password not correct...!";
                $this->load->view('layouts/header');
                $this->load->view('login_form');
                $this->load->view('layouts/footer'); 

                break;

            case 'not_activated':
                echo "Please activate your account before logging in...!";
                $this->load->view('layouts/header');
                $this->load->view('login_form');
                $this->load->view('layouts/footer'); 

                break;

            case 'incorrect_username':
                echo "Error loging in, password/username not correct...!";
                $this->load->view('layouts/header');
                $this->load->view('login_form');
                $this->load->view('layouts/footer'); 

                break;

            default:
                # code...
                break;
        }
    }
}


public function reset_password()
{
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) 
    {
        # code...
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email Address','trim|required|valid_email');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            # code...
            $this->load->view('layouts/header');
            $this->load->view('login/view_reset_password', array('error' => 'Please provide a valid email address'));
            $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
        }
        else
        {
            $email = trim($this->input->post('email'));
            $result = $this->model_login->email_exists($email);

            if ($result) 
            {
                $this->send_reset_password_email($email, $result);
                $this->load->view('layouts/header');
                $this->load->view('login/view_reset_password_sent', array('email' => $email));
                $this->load->view('layouts/footer');

            }
            else
            {

                $this->load->view('layouts/header');
                $this->load->view('login/view_login_reset_password_sent', array('error' => 'Email not registerd here'));
                $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {

        $this->load->view('layouts/header');
        $this->load->view('login/view_reset_password');
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
    }

}

public function reset_password_form($email, $email_code)
{
    if (isset($email) && isset($email_code)) 
    {
        #$email = trim($email);
        $email_hash = sha1($email.$email_code);
        $verified = $this->model_login->verify_reset_password_code($email, $email_code);

        if ($verified) 
        {
            $this->load->view('layouts/header');
            $this->load->view('login/view_update_password', 
                array(
                'email_hash'=>$email_hash,
                'email_code'=>$email_code,
                'email' => $email
                ));
            $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Can't get verified";
        }
    }
}

public function send_reset_password_email($email, $name)
{
    $this->load->library('email');
    $email_code = md5($this->config->item('salt').$name);

    $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
    $this->email->from($this->config->item('bot_email'),'reset password email');
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject('Please reset your password');

    $message = "<!DOCTYPE html><html>
    <head>
        <title>Reset Password</title>
    </head>
    <body>";
    $message .= "<p> Dear '{$name}'</p>";
    $message .='<p> we want to help you reset your password! please <strong> <a href="'.base_url().'index.php/login/reset_password_form/'.$email.'/'.$email_code.'">Click here </a> </strong> to reset your password</p>';
    $message .="<p>Thank you</p>";
    $message .="</body></html>";

    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->send();
}

public function update_password()
{
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $email_hash = $this->input->post('email_hash');
    $email_code = sha1($this->input->post('email').$this->input->post('email_code'));



    if (!isset($email,$email_hash) || ($email_hash != $email_code)) 
    {
        # code...
        die("Error updating password, unauthorize access");
    }

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_hash', 'Email Hash', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('new-password', 'password', 'trim|required|matches[new-password-again]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('new-password-again', 'password', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) 
    {
        $this->load->view('layouts/header');
        $this->load->view('login/view_update_password');
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
    }
    else
    {
        $result = $this->model_login->update_password();

        if ($result) 
        {
            $this->load->view('layouts/header');
            $this->load->view('login/view_update_password_success');
            $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
        }

        else
        {
            $this->load->view('layouts/header');
            $this->load->view('login/view_update_password',array(
                'error' => 'problem updating your password please contact site admin xyz@abc.com' ));
            $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

This is my model class model_login.php

```
<?php
class Model_login extends CI_Model
{

public function __construct()
{
    # code...
    parent::__construct();
}

public function login_user()
{
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    #$password = $this->input->post('password');

    $remember = $this->input->post('remember_me');

    $userpass = sha1($this->config->item('salt').$this->input->post('password'));

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}'  LIMIT 1";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    $row = $result->row();

    if($result->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        if($row->activated)
        {

            if ($row->password == $userpass) 
            {

                if ($remember) 
                {
                    $this->session->set_userdata('remember_me', TRUE);
                    $this->config->set_item('sess_expire_on_close', FALSE);
                }

                $sess_data = array(
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $userpass
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_data);

                return 'authenticated';
            }
            else
            {
                return 'incorrect_password';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 'not_activated';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 'incorrect_username';
    }
}

public function email_exists($email)
{
    $sql = "SELECT name , email FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    $row = $result->row();

    return ($result->num_rows() === 1 && $row->email) ? $row->name : false;
}

public function verify_reset_password_code($email, $code)
{
    $sql = "SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    $row = $result->row();

    if ($result->num_rows() === 1) 
    {
        return ($code == md5($this->config->item('salt').$row->name)) ? true : false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}


public function update_password()
{
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    echo $this->input->post('password')."<br>";
    $password = sha1($this->config->item('salt').$this->input->post('new-password'));

    echo $this->input->post('password')." hashed password <br>";

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET password = '{$password}' WHERE email = '{$email}' LIMIT 1";
    $this->db->query($sql);

    if (isset($sql)) {
            return true;
        }   
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}

private function set_session($session_data)
{
    $sess_data = array(
        'id' => $session_data['id'],
        'name' => $session_data['name'],
        'username' => $session_data['username'],
        'email' => $session_data['email'],
        'logged_in' => 1 );

    $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
}

}
?>
```

I'm setting session only when user logs in, Second problem is that there are so many records generated from time to time in db when we visiting/revisiting page, how do we handle record in db how do we delete the record when user logs out ? It just unset the data on calling

> $this->session->sess_destroy();

i have been searching on it from more than two days, if anyone can help i would be grateful. I had a moment when these setting/code worked spot on but i don't know what happened it all messed up. 
If any other file is required please tell me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Garbage Collector

As mentioned in the [(old) CodeIgniter docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html), CI has his own Garbage Collector. This is **still true** for CI 3.x

> The Session class has built-in garbage collection which clears out
>   expired sessions so you do not need to write your own routine to do
>   it.

As stated in the CI forum, the Garbage Collector uses [session.gc_probability](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) and session.gc_divisor values, provided by your `php.ini`, to invoke the cleanup process. (*By default, there is a chance of 1% to clean up the old sessions when making a session request*)

---

### Config Values

Anyway, I'd suggest you to set `sess_regenerate_destroy` to `FALSE` (according to the [newer CI docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?#session-preferences))

> Whether to destroy session data associated with the old session ID
>   when auto-regenerating the session ID. When set to FALSE, the data
>   will be later deleted by the garbage collector.

---

### Destroy session on tab close

`$config['sess_expire_on_close']` is **not available anymore** in CI 3.x

For detecting the browser or tab close by using JavaScript (but it is slightly unreliable) , take a look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20806014/3975480).
The easiest way to make a session last until the browser is being closed is to set the `session_expiration` value to `0`.

> The number of seconds you would like the session to last. If you would
>   like a non-expiring session (until browser is closed) set the value to
>   zero: 0

[Source](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences)

Comment: is this function called inside "sess_destroy()" ?

Comment: and so by this we don't need to care about deleting it ?

Comment: Nope, `sess_destroy()` only calls [session_destroy()](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/b4d719dc7fb3b010b53c09e7e82f979abf731ff9/system/libraries/Session/Session.php)

Comment: @HabibRehman: CI has his own Garbage Collector, so yes, you don't need to care about this! (Quote: "The Session class has built-in garbage collection which clears out expired sessions so you do not need to write your own routine to do it.")

Comment: thanks @manniL what about the first problem, direct link is getting access to the account :(

Comment: @HabibRehman Check this answer for the first problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20806014/3975480

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110123/discussion-between-habib-rehman-and-mannil).

Comment: @manniL ellislab does not deal with codeigniter any more use links from here http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Comment: @wolfgang1983 You are right, I almost forgot that. Fixed it.

Comment: For the first problem I have checked the solution and its not working, From the document's point of view, there is no difference between a page refresh and the window being closed: the document is unloaded in both cases. And it deletes the session even if page is refreshed

Comment: Have you changed the cfg values?

Comment: if you are talking about "$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;" yes i have changed it to FALSE again

Comment: @HabibRehman Please seperate your questions and ask each one for itself. I said everything to your problem(s) above.

Comment: The question is about CodeIgniter 3, while this answer refers to version 2.x - it is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Narf AFAIK there hasn't been a change on the garbage collection mechanism from 2.x to 3.x

Comment: @manniL One of the major changes between 2.x and 3.0 is a completely new Session library ... Not only is there are change in the GC mechanism, but other than the public method names, there's almost **nothing in common** between the two. And GC mechanics only answer half of the question anyway.

Comment: @Narf Alright, I'll elaborate my answer and do some researchs. Thanks alot

Comment: @manniL nope, it doesn't work by even doing "0" to "session_expiration", the only process i have found little helpful is doing it with JS. |
I have been able to make a difference between close a tab and refresh a tab the problem lies in "not doing anything when tab reloaded"