# codeigniter logout from all browser after a user change password

Tags: codeigniter, passwords, logout

I  worked in Codeigniter . I want to logged out a user from all browser when he change his current password.
I Want to destroy all session of the user.

Comment: [Use php's session_destroy() example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php). Even CI docs say to use it.

Comment: no that's not gonna work because i am using db base session

Comment: [I found this answer about CI's automatic db sessions clean up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36836530/3585500). Once you call session_destroy() CI gens a new session id and you'll never reference the old session record again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can achieve this, one would be having a random string inside the table for sessions, check this key on every http request made by the user, when they change the password you alter the key, and it would not match the users key anymore. When this happens you just manually log them out. One way of implementing this can be by using CodeIgniter hooks.