# How can i remove codeigniter session for logout when close browser?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, browser, logout

In chrome browser session not removing when client close the browser. I have tried to session expiration but its not working.

Comment: $config['sess_expiration'] = 0; is not working

Comment: in config.php file `$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;`  Whether to cause the session to expire automatically when the browser window is closed.

Comment: in { config.php file $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE; } is not working in chrome browser

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20806014/2275490

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery window close event

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo serverUrl; ?>/handle_session.php',
      type: 'POST',
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        alert("Successful");
      }
    });
    return "Do you really want to close?";
};
```

Hope this will help you.